# sql -changing column attribute to Unique

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a column of "email" in my table "user". I forget to make email as Unique in starting. Now I have lot of entries in my database and when I tries to change "email" as Unique, it show error "#1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'".

I do have some users with no email entry which means there are many Null value in column 'email'. How can I make 'email' unique now.

Question: Did unique means it can't contain any null value? Did I need to recreate a new table?

Comment: Are these live table?

Comment: `Did unique means it can't contain any null value`. Unique means unique, also null can be there one time

Comment: Need to rethink the logic here. One way to do this sort of thing would be to create another table called say valid_users (or rename users to contacts). Then you have one with a not null unique constraint, and some function to  create the record and drive all the functions that need the email from it. Or You do the uniqueness in business logic not the db layer.

Comment: Are the email adresses null or blank?

Comment: Some email address are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a backup table. Then clean your backup table by removing duplicate email and place dummy emails for null records.

Run an `Update` sql from backup table to your original table.

Comment: That would be dummy emails.

Comment: Also dummy email cannot be entered twice the same. You should considered entering this as a mandatory field in the app.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot make "email" Unique if there is an email that exist more than one time in your table so first of all you must  delete the duplicated emails than generate dummy emails for the null values